postgresql EXPLAIN gives seq scan rows = 12 for filter id < 10
I ran explain command on this query:
EXPLAIN
Select * from project_project where id < 10 FOR UPDATE


And the plan output:
"LockRows  (cost=0.00..6.57 rows=12 width=18305)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on project_project  (cost=0.00..6.45 rows=12 width=18305)"
"        Filter: (id < 10)"

How did the planner estimate rows=12?


without knowing the exact structure of your table (the DDL), it would be pretty hard to tell.  For example, currently it is unknown if id is a unique field?

yes id is primary key

seeing: “Plan Rows” is the estimated number of result rows ... when PostgreSQL cannot be certain, it will estimate at least one result to avoid very bad plans, you can do ANALYZE, to see if the explain changes....

Check the statistics for this table, for this column: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html

Read Using EXPLAIN.

Impossible to answer without seeing the pg_stats row for that column.
